# OWIN middleware does not get invoked for all requests

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, owin, owin-middleware

I am trying to add content security policy header in response header for `all` requests. So I have created OWIN middleware

```
public class SecurityHeaderMiddleware
{
    private readonly INonceService _nonceService = null;
    private readonly Func<Task> _next;
    public SecurityHeaderMiddleware(Func<Task> next, INonceService nonceService)
    {
        _nonceService = nonceService;
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {            
       // do something here to add CSP header in context.Response.Headers

        await _next.Invoke();
    }
```

Then to invoke my middleware for each request, I register my middleware in startup.cs `before PostResolveCache` stage marker as per the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34005442/route-all-requests-through-owin-middleware)

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Use((context, next) =>
        {
            var nonceService = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<INonceService>();
           var middleware = new SecurityHeaderMiddleware(next, nonceService);
            return middleware.Invoke(context);
        });

        app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.PostResolveCache);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
       {
         // set options here 
       });



        MvcHandler.DisableMvcResponseHeader = true;
    }
}
```

However, my middleware only gets invoked for actual page or any ajax request, it **does not** get invoked when browser make request to javascript, CSS or images

How do I invoke custom middleware for all requests? If not OWIN middleware then what are my options to add header for all requests in asp.net

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that owin middleware is only invoked for requests which are serviced by MVC handler.

Answer was to add catch all routing, so everything is routed to mvc handler.

Answer (score -1):

I guess the `PostAuthorize` [stage marker](https://github.com/evicertia/Katana/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Owin/Extensions/PipelineStage.cs) should be set to handle static content requests. It's even mentioned in the linked issue's comments:

```
app.Use(...);

app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.PostAuthorize);
```